# ms sql select data after specific date of the year regardless of year

Tags: sql, date

I want to select a data from column 'Birthday' which format is 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000' but I need to skip year, and pull out data from range yyyy-01.01 to yyyy.05.01 ?

Tryed underscores and percent but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `datepart(month, Birthday)` and embed that into the WHERE clause.

Link where I got it from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603/937093

[official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)